# How to avoid title fields for multi languages site in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, title, page-title

I want to remove title field from the "other language translation page". Before I installed title module and uninstall that even though the title fields shown with required field. How can I remove that title field?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal "title" is mandatory. The "auto node title" module will help. It hides tje field but fills it in the background. A pattern can be used. More info here: https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle